# REST API(sobjects). How to detect which field is system one on record?

Tags: rest

Does anybody know how to detect which field is system one
with this REST endpoint `services/data/v42.0/sobjects/{Entity}/describe`?
Is there any flag or something like that? or shall I just figure out from docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you drill down into the field describe there is a `custom` property.

[image: Field Describe]

Comment: to paraphrase Bill Clinton, "it all depends on your definition of <system>" - this property differentiates between OOTB fields and custom fields but does not tell you which are the audit fields or "special" fields you can't straightforwardly directly manipulate like `Account.LastReferencedDate`.  That said, OP should be clearer as to intent.

Comment: Yes, if they are trying to determine write-ability they would need to investigate other properties.